# Add textbox using vba with autosize function

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox, autosize

we can add new textbox using following code:

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextBox Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=1, Top:=1, Width:=300, Height:=100
```

I need to Create a Macro for adding a Note message textbox into .docm file which will look like this:

[image]

Please Note that (Require):

- The light bulb symbol needs to be cantered.
- The size of the grey box should adjust as more text is written
- The box shall stay together in case of page-break during writing.

then I realize there is not much we can do with shapes in ms word? please help me placing a textbox with which will fulfill above requirements.

Comment: Use a table otherwise you won't get the lightbulb automatically centered vertically in the text box. Use a quick part/building block instead of using code.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt can you help in building that with macro ? please. need just push start

Comment: Sorry, no. SO is not a code writing service. You need to do your own research and make your own attempt. As I have already pointed out to you, you can create the table and then save it as a quick part/building block, which is a much simpler solution.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Dear, is Quick part/building block is specific to machine? 
I am actually creating a .docm file with customize ribbon and icons which will run a macro to insert this kind of element onto document. here I am not sure how do I insert an icon.

Comment: Well, you should be creating a template (.dotm), not a document, and you store the quick part in the template.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have tried very hard. StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service. The auto-sizing is as easy as:

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
  Left:=1, Top:=1, Width:=300, Height:=100).TextFrame.AutoSize = 1
```